# Return type of wrapper function C++11

Tags: c++11

I have re-arranged an example regarding the std::forward with template.

I have used a wrapper function and everything is fine, if i declare it as void function. It works as expected.

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 template <typename T, typename U>
 auto summation(T const &a,  U const& b) -> decltype(T{}, U{})  {
    cout << "call by lvalue" << endl;
      return a+b;
 }

 template <typename T, typename U>
 auto summation(T&& a, U && b) -> decltype(T{},U{}) {
    cout << "call by rvalue" << endl;
      return a+b;
 }  

 template<typename T,typename U> void func(T&& a, U && b)  { 
  summation(forward<T>(a), forward<U>(b));

 }


 int main() {

 int x = 10;
 double y = 20;

 func(x,y);
 func(10,20);

 }
```

but if I want to return a type from a wrapper function, no matter what I used, I got error on lvalues function call ONLY, fund(x,y),   stating "....function does not match the arguments"... the other fund(10,20) works.

```
 template<typename T,typename U> auto func(T&& a, U && b) -> decltype(T{}, U{})  {
 return summation(forward<T>(a), forward<U>(b));

 }
```

and even using c++14 decltype(auto) for deducing the return type of forwarding functions and similar wrappers

```
 template<typename T,typename U> decltype(auto) func(T&& a, U && b) {
 return summation(forward<T>(a), forward<U>(b));

 }
```

it does not work either, stating "decline(type) is C++o1 extension..." that, thank you compiler, but it does help.

One non sense horrible solution is declare the return type or T or U as return type. This  compiles even if I got a warning stating "Reference to stack memory associated to local variable returned"

```
 template<typename T,typename U> U func(T&& a, U && b)   {
 auto res =  summation(forward<T>(a), forward<U>(b));
 return res;

 }
```

the return type of std::forward given (t) the object to be forwarded is

```
 static_cast<T&&>(t)
```

therefore it the first solution with auto should work but it does not.

Any suggestion on this ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure that `decltype(T{}, U{})` is a useful construct?

Comment: "decline(type) is C++o1 extension..." ?! decline?

Comment: Your second `summation` overload is **not** just for rvalues, it will also be called for non-const lvalues. You do not need two overloads, read http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: Why don't you simply use `template<typename T,typename U> auto func(T&& a, U && b) -> decltype (summation (forward<T>(a), forward<U>(b))) { return summation(forward<T>(a), forward<U>(b)); }`? It should handle all cases correctly.

Comment: Yes JohnB this works fine, and it works decltype(a+b) suggested by Jonathan but only if I use auto res = summation((forward<T>(a), forward<U>(b)). if I use return summation(forward<T>(a), forward<U>(b)) it fails to compile stating "no const lvalue reference to type double cannot bind a temporary of type decltype(int() + double());

Answer (score 5):

`decltype` means the type of the expression given in its argument. So

```
decltype(T {}, U {})
```

will be the type of the expression `T{}, U{}`. You have the comma operator here, and so the type of the expression is the type of the expression after the comma, which is `U{}`, hence `decltype (T{}, U{})` gives you type `U` (more precisely, `U &&`, I guess, since it is an rvalue).

What you want is

```
decltype(T{} + U{})
```

or

```
decltype(a+b)
```

(thanks to Jonathan Wakely, see comments).

Comment: `decltype(a+b)` would be better, the point of late-specified return types is they can refer to function arguments.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, it compiles using your suggestion.

Comment: But decltype(T{}+U{}) does not, what is the difference using a+b ?